# Eclipse error: "Failed to read the project description file" on importing project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I've just moved to Ubuntu and thought it would be a simple matter of importing my Android projects from my old workspace to my new workspace on Ubuntu. Ha!

I goto: New -> Project... -> Android Project From Existing Code. Select "Copy into workspace".

The error I receive is:

Problems occurred while refreshing local changes
Errors occurred while refreshing resources with the local file system.
Failed to read the project description file (.project) for 'MyProject'.  The file has been changed on disk, and it now contains invalid information.  The project will not function properly until the description file is restored to a valid state.

I've checked the project file and there's nothing wrong with it. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you copy the project?

Comment: I would recommend to manually browser the folder with your workspace and delete whatever has been copied from you project. Then go "copy" your project into the workspace (also manually). Next: New -> Project... -> Android Project From Existing Code. But DO NOT checked "Copy into workspace" anymore since you have it over there. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I did a file copy of the single project folder in the workspace from my Win 7 ntfs partition to a folder outside my workspace folder on Ubuntu, then selected "copy into workspace" to let eclipse move it into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to manually browse the folder with your workspace and delete whatever has been copied from you project. Then "copy" your project into the workspace (also manually). Next:

```
New -> Project... -> Android Project From Existing Code.
```

But DO NOT checked "Copy into workspace" anymore since you have it over there. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Ok I've got it to work with a slight varaition of your instructions. I deleted what was in my workspace on Ubuntu, imported the project folder directly from my Win 7 partition in Eclipse using "Copy into workspace" so I get the project folder onto Ubuntu...and it works! No idea why copying the workspace first from Win 7 then importing causes errors but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when importing a git repository and auto-adding the projects on Windows 7 after upgrading my machine (I also changed Eclipse versions at the same time).

I deleted the projects from my Eclipse workspace, then re-imported them, and then it worked.